# How to log request for particular URL pattern in apache

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, httpd

How do I configure apache to log requests in the request URL matches particular regex pattern ?

Comment: Please clarify because all requests are logged in access.log

Comment: @RomeoNinov, yes but I want to log only certain URL matching patterns

Comment: All you can do is to use the apache log engine. If you want to extract by pattern this is different question. And my humble advise is to keep all the logs :) Check also here for some options to customize log: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog

Comment: I know how to grep for it, My question is specifically for enabling logging for url pattern

Comment: good pointer, let me check if this setenv works in my case

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `SetEnvIf` directive and add any matching `Request_URI`'s to a custom log. For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /request/to/match$ mycustomlogfile
CustomLog mycustomlogfile.log common env=mycustomlogfile
```

For more specifics on how to use `SetEnvIf`, check out this how to page on HowToForge.com [How To Tell Apache To Not Log Certain Requests In Its Access Log](https://www.howtoforge.com/setenvif_apache2) (Note: Although the tutorial is about not logging certain requests in apache, it's still good information on using `SetEnvIf` directive.)